# Getting list of values as array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have this query:

```
SELECT id FROM a
```

`id` is of type `integer`

I want to get the result as integer array: `[26053,26021]`, this result is returned to a function which iterates on the elements.

Based on what I read in the manual I wrote this query:

```
select array_to_string( array( SELECT id FROM a where ... ), ',' )
```

The thing is that it returns me a string `26053,26021` and when I iterate on the result it does:

```
    ... (id =2 or id =6 or id =0 or id =5 or id =3 or id =,
         or id =2 or id =6 or id =0 or id =2 or id =1)
```

As you can see it treats the result as string not as array, each char is an element.

How do I get just an array? Is the only solution to convert the string back to array? Isn't there a way to convert it directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the simple case with a single result row, an [**array constructor**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS) is best (simplest, fastest). You actually have that already, just remove `array_to_string()`, which converts the array to a string (as the name implies):

```
SELECT ARRAY(SELECT id FROM a WHERE ... ) AS id_arr;
```

For cases with multiple result rows, look to the aggregate function [`array_agg()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html). Example:

```
SELECT b, array_agg(id) AS id_arr
FROM   a
WHERE  ...
GROUP  BY b;
```

Aside:
The standard Postgres syntax for an array constant (text representation of array) would be `'{26053,26021}'` - with curly braces, and single-quoted. Depending on the context, you may or may not have to add an explicit cast: `'{26053,26021}'::int[]` Or you could use another array constructor, this time based on integer constants instead of a subquery: `ARRAY[26053,26021]`.

`[26053,26021]` is something in between that wouldn't work either way.

Comment: Aside: Instead of "iterating on the elements", there is often a superior SQL-only solution.

Comment: That works. Is there a way to return the elements as `(26053,26021)` and not as `{26053,26021}` ? Later I use query like: `SELECT * FROM .. WHERE id IN result` where result is the array I got from this query.  It won't work with `{ }`

Comment: @John: Maybe you should ask another question demonstrating your exact use case.